# Play a sound that accompanies a random image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a random image generator like so:

```
<head>

<script language="JavaScript">
function pickimg(){
    var imagenumber = 4 ;
    var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
    var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
    images = new Array
    images[1] = "image1.jpg"
    images[2] = "image2.jpg"
    images[3] = "image3.jpg"
    images[4] = "image4.jpg"
    var image = images[rand1]
    document.randimg.src = image
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="pickimg()">

<a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><body onLoad="pickimg()">

<a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE" name="randimg" border=0 width="100%" height="100%"></a></a>

</body>
```

When image1.jpg is shown, I'd like to also play sound1.wav. When image2.jpg is shown, I'd like to also play sound2.wav, and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the HTML5 `<audio>` tag

Comment: Playing the audio isn't my trouble; it's making it match the correct image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the same logic that you've already implemented, you could do something like this:

```
<body onLoad="pickimg()">
    <a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><body onLoad="pickimg()">
    <a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><IMG SRC="YOUR IMAGE" name="randimg" border=0 width="100%" height="100%"></a></a>
    <audio id="audioTag"></audio>
    <script>
        function pickimg() {
            var imagenumber = 4;
            var randomnumber = Math.random();
            var rand1 = Math.round((imagenumber - 1) * randomnumber) + 1;
            images = new Array
            images[1] = "image1.jpg"
            images[2] = "image2.jpg"
            images[3] = "image3.jpg"
            images[4] = "image4.jpg"
            var image = images[rand1];
            document.randimg.src = image

            var sounds = new Array
            sounds[1] = "sound1.wav"
            sounds[2] = "sound2.wav"
            sounds[3] = "sound3.wav"
            sounds[4] = "sound4.wav"
            var sound = sounds[rand1];
            audioTag.src = sound;
            audioTag.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This is untested, and there's better ways of doing this, but I used your logic that's already implemented to make it easier for you.

FYI - the "Language" attribute of  has not been used for years.

Comment: Thanks! This is great!

You don't have to rewrite or anything, but how should I have thought to do this better?

Comment: You can actually remove the arrays completely since your file names include a number and then just insert the number directly into the file name.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/Pu7Bu/

Comment: Is there a way to make this automatically advance every X milliseconds without clicking?